# 3 ants on each vertex of a triangle probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There is a triangle and there are 3 ants on each vertex of the triangle. The 9 ants start to move randomly along the edges of the triangle with an equal possibility of 1/2 along both the edges available. What is the probability that AT LEAST two ants will collide? I have tried solving and came up with an answer 237/256 but do not know if its the correct answer can someone help me? Thanks in advance. :)

Edit : calculate the probability for just 1 step i.e all ants move from one vertex to adjacent vertex n stop

Comment: Is the question what the probability is that they collide just after the first step? Or after two? Three? Infinite? Until they have visited all veritices? Until they have done 1 full loop? Or ...?

Comment: `3 ants on each vertex` means you have 9 ants.

Comment: @bram28 find probability aftr first step

Comment: -wolfies Thats rt total 9 ants

Answer (score 2):

The only way for there not to be any collision is for the ants to all move clockwise or all move counterclockwise: once $1$ of the ants moves clockwise, then that will force all of the $3$ ants from the next vertex to move clockwise as well, forcing the next $3$ as well, and thus forcing the last $2$ as well. Same for counterclockwise.

So, there are only $2$ possible ways out of the $2^9=512$ possible movements for the $9$ ants for there *not* to be a collision, and since moving in each direction for each ant is equally likely, you get that there is a probability of $\frac{2}{512}=\frac{1}{256}$ for there not to be any collision, meaning that the probability there to be at least one collision is:

$$1-\frac{2}{512}=1-\frac{1}{256}=\boxed{\frac{255}{256}}$$

Comment: There r 3 ants on each vertex :) total 9

Comment: @shourabh OH! OK, thanks, I'll revise my answer

Comment: Great thank you and what will be the probability  exactly two ants collide (exactly one collision)keeping all conditions same..

Comment: @shourabh If two ants colliding into one ant counts as two collisions, then that probability is zero! It is impossible for one ant to collide with one ant, and have no further collisions: if you ever have a colision that involves two ants, then that means that the other two wants from each of those vertices went the other way, and so the ants from the third vertex would all collide with them.

Comment: i mean one ant colliding with other and counting that as one collision

Comment: so 1 ant colliding with 2 ants counts as 1 collision?  Would 2 ants colliding with 2 ants also count as 1 collision?

Comment: No sir do not confuse what you assumed in the beginning was correct same collision apply here i just tried to be clear 
1 collision is 2 ants collide with each other(a standard 2d collision) . No other type of collision is involved in this system 
Find probability that exactly 1 collision occurs.

Comment: @shourabh OK, so if you have 1 ant colliding with 2 ants that does *not* count as a collision then?  And if 2 ants collide with 2 ants, is that no collision? Or 1 collision? Or 2 collisions?